# If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$, does $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x+k) - f(x) = 0$ for any $k$?

Tags: calculus

As the title says, if I have a differentiable real function, $f$, and it satisfies

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$

is $f$ guaranteed to also satisfy

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x+k) - f(x) = 0$

for any $k$?

My intuition tells me this should be true, since if the derivative approaches $0$ when $x$ approaches infinity, then the graph of $f$ is flattening out towards the right. If $f$ is flattening out towards the right, then for large values of $x$,

$f(x) \approx f(x+1) \approx f(x+2) \approx \cdots$

or more simply,

$f(x) \approx f(x+k)$

which rearranges to

$f(x+k) - f(x) \approx 0$

I'm not well versed in math enough to confirm the general case, but the constant functions, $\frac{1}{x}$, $\ln x$, and $\sqrt{x}$ all satisfy the implication.

Comment: let $k=0$......

Comment: $f(x+k)-f(x)=kf'(x+\theta k)$ where $\theta\in (0,1)$ and $\theta$ depends on $x$ and $k.$

Comment: Whenever you have expressions like $f(b) - f(a) $ and want to say something about the derivative, you should immediately try the mean value theorem.

Comment: @KamalSaleh I’m pretty sure $k$ here is universally quantified.

Comment: @KamalSaleh I asked about whether the first limit implies the second limit, regardless of the value of $k$, not about a specific value of $k$ such that the second limit holds true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. I have a proof that uses [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Basically, if you use MVT for $f(y)$ on interval $[x,x+t]$ you will get a point $c\in [x,x+t]$ for which $f^{\prime}(c)=\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}$, or $tf^{\prime}(c)=f(x+t)-f(x)$. Since $f^\prime(c) \to 0$, we also have $f(x+t)-f(x)\to 0$.

Formally, since $\lim_{x\to \infty}f^{\prime}(x)=0$, for any value $\epsilon>0$ there is $N=N(\epsilon)$ such that if $x>N$, then $|f^{\prime}(x)|<\epsilon$. If $t$ is fixed, and $x>N$, apply MVT for $f()$ on interval $[x,x+t]$ to get
$c\in [x,x+t]$ for which $f^{\prime}(c)=\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}$, or $tf^{\prime}(c)=f(x+t)-f(x)$. Since $|f^\prime(c)|<\epsilon$, we also have $|f(x+t)-f(x)|<\epsilon t$.

So $f(x+t)-f(x)$ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing appropriate $\epsilon$ and taking sufficiently large $x>N(\epsilon)$.